# Define a for loop with pre specified variable values

Tags: arrays, unix, for-loop

Below I pasted a small part of my code which covers the question I have. I'm running three `for` loops in a Unix script. The first loop `n` just runs over integer values. The second loop `k` runs over integer values as well, but I change it later for `kappa` to represent all values divided by 10, in this case the range is `0:0.1:10`.

Now, my question concerns the third loop. I am a total beginner with Unix programming so this might be a very basic question, still I can't seem to figure it out. The third loop is supposed to cover an array of predefined values, i.e. `p=[0 1/15 1/12 1/10 2/15 1/6 1/5 1/4 1/3]`. I have defined `jmax` as 9 but yet I don't know how to set these corresponding `p` values to this loop parameter. Basically I would just like to set up an array holding these values and then assign them, can anyone please give me some directions as how to do that?

Please note: due to other use of `$j` I have to leave the start of the `for` loop intact!

Code partial:

```
   for ((n=0;n<${nmax};n++)); do # first loop
       for ((k=0;k<${kmax};k++)); do # second loop
           for ((j=0;j<${jmax};j++)); do # third loop

               # specify you job ......
               kappa=$(echo "scale=10; ${k}/10" | bc -l)
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would create an array and loop over it:

```
# create an array
p=(0 1/15 1/12 1/10 2/15 1/6 1/5 1/4 1/3)

# loop over the elements in the array
for j in "${p[@]}"; do
   echo "$j"
done
```

Take a look at the [Arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html) chapter of the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide.

Comment: I thought this was the answer what I was looking for, but now I realise that I need to keep the definition of the for loop intact (`for ((j=0;j<${jmax};j++));`). I can still define p before the for loop, but could you explain in your answer how I can extract the first value of p within the for loop?

Comment: Ok, I think I've actually figured it out myself, so saying i have to use `for ((j=0;j<${jmax};j++));`, I define `p` as you stated in your answer and then within the for-loop I can just use `prob=$(echo ${p[$j]})`. Can you go over that and if agreed change that in your answer? It might help others out! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specifically need an array for your script, and if your array entries do not contain whitespace characters, there is an even easier solution:

```
# Assign all values that should be looped over to a normal string variable,
# with each value separated by a space
p="0 1/15 1/12 1/10 2/15 1/6 1/5 1/4 1/3"

# Loop over all values in p
for value in p; do
  # Access each value in p using $value
done
```

Comment: To keep the whole script as general as possible I'd prefer @dogbane's solution, but thanks!